# Can i'm custom field name collection.group mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
 const formFieldName = request.query.fromFieldName;
 const outputFieldName = request.query.OutputFieldName;

 db.contest.aggregate([
    {
      "$group" : {
         _id:"$province",
         count: {
           $sum: 1
         }
       }
    }
 ])
```

Can i'm custom '_id' with outputFieldName and '$provice' with fromFieldName?

Thanks

Comment: could you please ask question properly? I am unable to understand what is the problem?

Comment: Can i'm use '_id' as 'outputFieldName' and '$provice' as 'fromFieldName'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got it right, let me know if not but you want to use `formFieldName` and `outputFieldName` as parameters in your aggregation?

if so the answer is Yes!

```
db.contest.aggregate([
    {
      "$group" : {
         _id: `$${formFieldName}`,
         count: {
           $sum: 1
         }
       }
    }
 ])
```

Edit:
And now to add `outputFieldName` we will use project:

```
{
  $project: {
    [outputFieldName]: "$_id",
    count: "$count",
    _id: 0
   }
}
```

Comment: `db.contest.aggregate([
    {
      "$group" : {
         `$${outputFieldName}`: `$${formFieldName}`,
         count: {
           $sum: 1
         }
       }
    }
 ])` and like this yup?

Comment: No, group has to get `_id` as a field. so you can't really do that. however you could project with the `outputFieldName` name after the group, ill add it to my answer.